# Does ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject block the current thread or a thread-pool thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr

From reading [the documentation of the `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02x3daw5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, it is not clear whether:

1. It blocks the current thread while waiting on the `EventWaitHandle` and then commissions the `WaitOrTimerCallback` on a thread pool thread, or
2. It commissions a thread pool thread to wait on the wait handle and then on that same thread execute the `WaitOrTimerCallback` once the wait handle has been signaled.
3. It blocks the current thread and when the wait handle is signaled, it calls the `WaitOrTimerCallback` on the current thread. But this would be the equivalent functionality of `WaitHandle.WaitOne()`. Also, it would not involve the thread pool at all.

Which of the three does it do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is none of the above, 2) is closest.  The exact details are pretty convoluted, most of the code is buried in the CLR and it has changed across .NET versions.  You can have a look-see at the current version [in the CoreCLR source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/win32threadpool.cpp), I'll give the 10,000 feet view.

Key is that it doesn't block, the work is done by a dedicated unmanaged thread.  Called the "wait thread" in the source code, it uses the WaitForMultipleObjects() winapi function to wait on all registered waits.  If there is none (left) it just sleeps.  The thread is woken up from either by a QueueUserApc() if the wait list changes so it can resume waiting with an updated list.

Once one of the wait objects get signaled, it uses ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() to invoke the callback delegate target on a threadpool thread.  If the `executeOnlyOnce` argument was true then the wait handle is removed from the list.  And it quickly resumes waiting with WFMO.  The thread never ends.

The `executeOnlyOnce` argument is important btw, hilarity ensues if you pass *false* and you use a ManualResetEvent.  The thread explosion triggered by the MRE's Set() method is an interesting artifact to observe :)  You can see the wait thread in the debugger's Debug > Windows > Threads when you enable unmanaged debugging.  It doesn't have an interesting name however.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's been a while since I touched C++ and so my understanding of what I read from the CLR source is limited, but I am trying. Where may I find the definition / body of `QueueUserAPC`? How do I search for the body of a function? I just used the **Find** window in the browser because the call to `QueueUserAPC` is not qualified by any receiver / object, so I searched in the same file but couldn't find it. Also, I don't see any call to `WaitForMultipleObjects/Ex` in the source code for the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method in that file. Where are you looking?

Comment: Finally, what is APC? I infer it is some Win32 metaphor for a work item / work that needs doing?

Comment: It is an operating system function, so it WFMO.  Source code is only visible to Microsoft employees.  Just look them up in MSDN to see what they do.  APC is Asynchronous Procedure Call, .NET's BeginInvoke() is roughly similar.  Very roughly. the notion of alertable threads that can execute APCs is not available in .NET, too difficult to do correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked the documentation for `QueueUserAPC`. While I am a huge fan and a long-time consumer of the Win32 API, I think I still need to read up a lot before I can understand what's going on there. :-) Many thanks for your help, as always. I think I need to continue studying threading for a year or so before I *get* it.

Comment: What is "WFMO?" Please spell out any obscure acronyms for those of us who have not heard of them before. Thanks for doing so for "APC."

Comment: I think they meant "so is WaitForMultipleObjects (WFMO)". The typo from "is" to "it" didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The following test code demonstrates the behavior specifically enough to answer your question.

```
static bool bQuit = false;
static string LastEntry;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    EventWaitHandle ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "TestEvent");
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Thread1));
    Console.WriteLine("TestEvent created.");

    while (!bQuit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to signal TestEvent.\nPress 2 to quit.");
        switch (LastEntry = Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "1":
                ewh.Set();
                break;
            case "2":
                bQuit = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    ewh.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to finish exiting.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Thread1(object data)
{
    WaitHandle wh = EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("TestEvent");
    RegisteredWaitHandle rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
        wh, new WaitOrTimerCallback(Thread2), null, Timeout.Infinite, false);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} registered another thread to run when TestEvent is signaled.",
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    while(!bQuit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is running.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    rwh.Unregister(wh);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is exiting", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

static void Thread2(object data, bool t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} started", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    while(!bQuit && (LastEntry != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is running. Enter {0} to end it",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} is exiting", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

The output is:

```
TestEvent created.
Thread 6 registered another thread to run when TestEvent is signaled.
Thread 6 is running.
Press 1 to signal TestEvent.
Press 2 to quit.
Thread 6 is running.
Thread 6 is running.
1
Press 1 to signal TestEvent.
Press 2 to quit.
Thread 13 started
Thread 13 is running. Enter 13 to end it
Thread 6 is running.
Thread 13 is running. Enter 13 to end it
Thread 6 is running.
Thread 13 is running. Enter 13 to end it
1
Press 1 to signal TestEvent.
Press 2 to quit.
Thread 14 started
Thread 14 is running. Enter 14 to end it
Thread 6 is running.
Thread 13 is running. Enter 13 to end it
Thread 14 is running. Enter 14 to end it
Thread 6 is running.
Thread 13 is running. Enter 13 to end it
Thread 14 is running. Enter 14 to end it
13
Press 1 to signal TestEvent.
Press 2 to quit.
Thread 6 is running.
Thread 13 is exiting
Thread 14 is running. Enter 14 to end it
Thread 6 is running.
Thread 14 is running. Enter 14 to end it
2
Press Enter to finish exiting.
Thread 6 is exiting
Thread 14 is exiting
```

So the answer to your question is, I think, #2.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following test to answer my question. The answer is #2.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadPoolRegisterWaitForSingleObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var allTasksWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            Action action = () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Long task running on {(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? "thread pool" : "foreground")} thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) ;
            };

            //var result = action.BeginInvoke((state) =>
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Async call back says long thing done.");
            //}, null);

            var result = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);

            Console.WriteLine("Main thread not blocked.");

            var registerWaitHandle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, (s, b) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Main long task finished.");
                Console.WriteLine($"WaitOrTimerCallback running on {(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? "thread pool" : "foreground")} thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

                allTasksWaitHandle.Set();
            }, null, 5000, true);

            allTasksWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine("All threads done.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, this particular sentence from [the documentation of the `ThreadPool` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests that the call back is called on a thread pool thread.

*When you use registered wait handles, a system thread monitors the status of the wait handles. When a wait operation completes, a worker thread from the thread pool executes the corresponding callback function.*