# Creating I/O-Based Tasks using Task.Factory.FromAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm new to async programming, just a question on Creating I/O-Based Tasks. My textbook gives  some example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Task<string> downloadTask = DownloadWebPageAsync("http://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/5SecondPage.aspx");
   while (!downloadTask.IsCompleted)
   {
      Console.Write(".");
      Thread.Sleep(250);
   }
   Console.WriteLine(downloadTask.Result);
}

private static Task<string> DownloadWebPageAsync(string url)
{
   return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DownloadWebPage(url));
}

private static string DownloadWebPage(string url)
{
   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
   WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
   var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
   {
      // this will return the content of the web page
      return reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

and the author says: **This all looks good until you start to analyze the cost of achieving this asynchronous operation. In effect you now have two threads running for the duration of the download: the one running inside Main and the one attempting to get the response from the web site. The thread responsible for getting the content is spending most of its time blocked on the line reader.ReadToEnd(); you have taken a thread from the thread pool, denying others the chance to use it, only for it to spend most of the time idle.
A far more efficient approach would be to create a thread to request the data from the web server, give the thread back to the thread pool, and when the data arrives, obtain a thread from the pool to process the results. To achieve this prior to .NET 4.5, the I/O methods in the library use the APM idiom:**

```
public virtual IAsyncResult BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, object state);
public virtual WebResponse EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
```

**so a better approach is** :

```
private static Task<string> BetterDownloadWebPageAsync(string url)
{
   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
   IAsyncResult ar = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
   Task<string> downloadTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<string>(ar, iar =>
   {
      using (WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(iar))
      {
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
      }
   });
   return downloadTask;
}
```

I can understand that `IAsyncResult ar = request.BeginGetResponse(null, null);` is to enqueue the task on threadpool, later a threadpool will assign a thread(let's say it is called threadA) to get the job(to request the data) done.

Below is my questions:

Q1-I'm confused with the use of 'Task.Factory.FromAsync', what does it do? does it enqueue a new Task on the threadpool so sometimes later the threadpool will assign another thread to execute this task? why we cannot use `Task.Factory.FromAsync`?

Q2-When all the data arrives from the web site, how does the threadpool know the fact that all data arrives and assign a new thread to process the results?

Comment: Have a look at [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/tpl-and-traditional-async-programming#wrapping-apm-operations-in-a-task) for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, a thread is a thread, there is no difference between an 'IO thread' and any other thread. I think your book may be misleading you if it uses those terms. The only thing that would make a thread an 'IO thread' is if you decide that it can only be used to process IO operations, and you implement it that way.

However, there *is* a difference between **blocking** operations, like `Thread.Sleep()` and `WaitHandle.WaitOne()`, and **non-blocking** operations, like `BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse` and many of the APM methods.

- A **blocking** operation will *put the thread to sleep*, so the thread is doing nothing, but it still exists and it still uses the same amount of memory.
- A **non-blocking** operation *starts* the operation, and then returns immediately. When the operation is complete, a wait handle is signalled *by the operating system*. The calling thread *does not* get put to sleep.

The article ['There Is No Thread'](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) that was linked to on your other question gives a particularly good explanation of how this works. I think you understand this much already. So a naive implementation of `FromAsync` would look like this:

```
public Task<TResult> FromAsync<TResult>(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Func<IAsyncResult, TResult> endMethod)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted)
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        return endMethod(asyncResult);
    });
}
```

There's a problem with this, though - the call to `asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` puts the thread to sleep, so this defeats the whole purpose of using a non-blocking method. So how do we wait for a `WaitHandle` without blocking the current thread? There is a method specifically for this purpose: [RegisterWaitForSingleObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public Task<TResult> FromAsync<TResult>(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Func<IAsyncResult, TResult> endMethod)
{
    RegisteredWaitHandle handle;
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    void OnAsyncResultSignalled(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
        if (asyncResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            handle.Unregister(null);
            tcs.TrySetResult(endMethod(asyncResult));
        }
    }

    handle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
        asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle,
        OnAsyncResult,
        null,
        TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        false);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I'm no expert in this area, so I'm sure it could implemented more efficiently, but this gives you the general idea.

I've created a `TaskCompletionSource`, and registered a callback to be run when the AsyncResult's wait handle is signalled. This means that until the wait handle is signalled, this callback is not being executed, and no threads are being blocked.

Of course, you're probably then going to ask *'how does RegisterWaitForSingleObject work'*? As a very broad explanation, the thread pool keeps *one* dedicated thread to wait for *all* registered events. So *yes*, a thread is being blocked, but no matter how many events you register this way, only *one* thread is being blocked. For more details on this, see [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37500329/2363967).

Comment: It seems that I have a misunderstanding in APM and I/O threads, could you please take a look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984298/apm-and-i-o-thread

Comment: I see your other question has been removed, but I managed to get a look at it before it was. I've updated my answer so hopefully it addresses more of your questions now, and I've learnt a bit while doing it too.